# Anaconda can't find PyPDF2

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, pypdf

I'm trying to import PyPDF2 on Anaconda macOS, but it isn't working

here's my import: `import PyPDF2`

I keep getting the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'`

I'm on mac, and when I '$ conda list', PyPDF is there

```
pypdf2                    3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Any ideas on what's going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to run this script on the command line?  You may be getting the operating system's version of Python, which is different from Anaconda's version.

Comment: i'm running the conda list command in terminal and the import in jupyternotebook

Comment: Have you configured Jupyter to use the conda installation of Python?  Alternatively, have you used Jupyter to install PyPDF2?